# How to access Google SQL tables outside App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

How can I access my Google SQL models days created in Google App Maker from outside the application?

For example, how do I access my App Maker model data through an App Script in a Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Here is some reference material https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#creating_google_cloud_sql_connections. I would look at that and maybe try some scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options I use to access the data in our Cloud SQL database:

**phpMyAdmin**
This web-based app lets you administer your SQL databases. It includes an export option to save date in CSV, Excel, and other formats.  Although you can use this free website: http://www.phpmyadmin.co/, I prefer the option of installing my own version on Google's App Engine (this approach may entail costs for your organization).  Follow these instructions to set it up:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine

**MySQLWorkBench**
This free app runs on your computer and let's you administer your SQL database.  You can easily export data in CSV and other formats.

**Spreadsheet Export Module from App Maker University**
This option may be the easiest if all you want to do is export data to a Google Sheet.  Note that the exported data is static unlike the other options which provide a live view of your SQL database.  It's available from App Maker University for $9.99 here https://www.appmakeruniversity.com/product/spreadsheet-export-module/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [official Google Guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting) describes how to export a cloud SQL database into a CSV file (which then can be easily imported as spreadsheet). Assuming that you use a Google Cloud SQL database, you should be set.